# Python parse DNS response headers

Tags: python, header, dns

i want to know if there is a way to generate dns queries via python and get the dns responses as well as their headers so as to see things in the dns response as NXDomain, connection refused, server failure etc..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Sure, there is a library called [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) that does exactly that.

Comment: the problem though is that i can not find a simple example for using dnspython

Comment: @Dandy Roll: None? There's an [Examples](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html) page linked right from the front page.